# Can I test for visual regressions in my responsive design?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, responsive-design

My Ruby on Rails site has a responsive design. Can I write tests for visual regressions? For example, my site fits in an iPhone 5's viewport without horizontal scrolling. If `offset-x: hidden` isn't set, and I unintentionally extend the width of an image past the viewport, my site will have horizontal scrolling (pictured below). This is undesirable. Does a visual regression test method such as `assert_horizontal_scroll(0)` or `assert_page_width == "480px", :viewport_width => "480px"` exist?

```
+---------+      +---------+
| PAGE    |      | PAGE    |
| +-----+ |      | +---------+
| | IMG | |      | |   IMG   |
| +-----+ |      | +---------+
|         |      |         |
+---------+      +---------+
```

EDIT: Let me try to clarify: I currently preview changes to my styles in a fullscreen browser window. If I make changes that could affect the way my site appears on mobile screens, I'll resize that browser window to match the dimensions of a mobile device, then see if everything looks ok. I want to automate the process of "seeing if everything looks ok" on small screens via a unit test so that I don't have to resize my browser to each device width.

EDIT: Another example: I want an element to be 50% transparent, and I set `opacity: .5`. I want to test the element's opacity, so that if later CSS styles unintentionally set that element's opacity to 1, I'll know because my test will fail. Or if a particular browser (early IE) doesn't support opacity, the test will also fail.

Comment: I haven't tried either of these, but [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) or [CasperJS](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/06/04/simpler-ui-testing-with-casperjs-2/?utm_source=TWIT&utm_medium=social_media&utm_content=CasperJS&utm_campaign=testing&utm_term=content&mpc=SM-TWIT-web-EN-100-CasperJS-testing) may be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) is "a CasperJS
  module for automating visual regression testing with PhantomJS and
  Resemble.js. For testing Web apps, live style guides and responsive
  layouts."
- [CasperJS](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/06/04/simpler-ui-testing-with-casperjs-2/) "is a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS, written in JavaScript. It allows us to test websites a lot like PHPUnit or JUnit allow us to test our code."
- [Wraith](http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/56884056177/wraith) is a tool for "testing CSS changes, both deliberate and unintentional." It's used "to compare screenshots of pages, at the pull request level and when merged into master."

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. Are you trying to fit the image to the resolution regardless of it's size or do you want to crop it?

If you want responsive image just use css:

http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/eqE9J/

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what I'm trying to ask. See my updated question.